# Detecting a cycle in an undirected graph using DFS

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have the following code which is a modification of DFS that detects whether an undirected graph has a cycle.

```
graph = {
    'A' : set(['B', 'C']),
    'B' : set(['D', 'E', 'A']),
    'C' : set(['A', 'F']),
    'D' : set(['B']),
    'E' : set(['B', 'F']),
    'F' : set(['C','E'])
}

def find_cycle(graph, start):
    colors = { node : "WHITE" for node in graph }
    colors[start] = "GRAY"
    stack = [start]
    while stack:
        for neighbor in graph[stack[-1]]:
            if colors[neighbor] == "GRAY":
                return True
            elif colors[neighbor] == "WHITE":
                colors[neighbor] = "GRAY"
                stack.append(neighbor)
            else:
                colors[neighbor] = "BLACK"
                stack.pop()
     return False
```

No matter what my graph looks like, it always returns true and I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. The algorithm works when I trace it on paper but the implementation doesn't translate to working code.

Comment: Is your code indented as you copied above?

Comment: And where is your return statement?

Comment: @grigor Yes it is.

Comment: Well then your function isn't indented correctly. And I don't see any return statements other than `return True`.

Comment: @grigor updated but it still only returns true

Comment: Could you also post an example of a graph you're running on? I mean how is the graph represented?

Comment: @grigor It's an adjacency list. I have updated my question. In that example, it will return true because there is a cycle. but if remove the connection between 'F' and 'C' there should no longer be a cycle.

Comment: Your title says "undirected", but your description says "directed", and so is your graph.

Comment: @trincot I'm sorry, I meant undirected. how is my graph directed ?

Comment: I see: it is undirected as long as you don't randomly add/remove nodes from some sets: you have indeed made it undirected. See grigor's answer: you'll always consider one edge as being a cycle (travelling forward/backward across the same edge and discovering you already visited that node).

Comment: @trincot can you please point me to where i need to fix my algorithm specifically ?

Comment: Yes, did you see my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is visiting as neighbor the node you just came from, and so you travel the same edge forward and backward, only to find you already visited the node you actually came from. But the algorithm wrongly concludes that this represents a cycle.

So it is not enough to check whether a neighbor has already been visited. That only represents a cycle if the corresponding edge had not yet been travelled before.

One way to make the algorithm work, is to store the edge on the stack, not just a node. Then you can easily check if a neighbor is the other end of the edge, and then just ignore it:

```
def find_cycle(graph, start):
    colors = { node : "WHITE" for node in graph }
    colors[start] = "GRAY"
    stack = [(None, start)] # store edge, but at this point we have not visited one
    while stack:
        (prev, node) = stack.pop()  # get stored edge
        for neighbor in graph[node]:
            if neighbor == prev:
                pass # don't travel back along the same edge we came from
            elif colors[neighbor] == "GRAY":
                return True
            else: # can't be anything else than WHITE...
                colors[neighbor] = "GRAY"
                stack.append((node, neighbor)) # push edge on stack
    return False
```

Note that the graph you presented in the question has a cycle:

```
   A---C 
  /     \
 B---E---F
```

If you take out the connection between C and F (for example), the above code will return `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is not correct for an undirected graph. You're simple going to detect a cycle as the very first edge between A and B (B is a neighbor of A and A is a neighbor of B).